# the svn commit of source control will hang the Xcode 5

Tags: ios, svn, xcode5

After I upgraded the Xcode to 5, the commit in source control menu of Xcode 5 will hang the Xcode. The commit popup window won't dismiss (the tool bar always show committing) and the Xcode don't have any response.

But when I check the svn status in command line, it is said that the files have been committed. No local changed files exist.

If you have any solution on this, I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: too little information to tell what's going on. What does log tell? Also, what is the SVN server version?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor svn version is 1.7.10, XCode Version is 5.0(5A1413). I don't know where to see the log since it is the function integrated in the XCode, (the command line svn e\does work as I said, I checked the svn status). I just click the menu of XCode, Source Control -> Commit..., a window is poped up, I click the commit, then the toolbar of XCode shows committing and no response any more. the popup window doesn't dismiss.

Comment: @RoyMa I am facing similar issue, have you got any resolution?